# Open WRT mini router: mobile modem installation

Tags: openwrt, router, modem

The [GL-AR300M](http://gl-inet.com/products/gl-ar300m) mini router runs a Linux based *Open WRT* system, making it highly configurable. Recently i have been trying to use the 3G modem *Option Globetrotter GI0505* i have with it, but without success.

By running `dmesg | grep usb` it seems that it is detected only as a USB drive, and `ls /dev/` doesn’t show any *ttyUSB* devices. If *usb-modeswitch* is run with `usbmode -l`, it does say that there is a *Found device: 0af0:d055 (Manufacturer: “Option Wireless Technology”, Product: “Globetrotter GI0505”, Serial: “Serial Number”),* but the `-s` flag doesn’t seem to modeswitch anything.

What is missing here?